# Why do I have a deadlock even though it includes an endless loop?

Tags: go, concurrency, multiprocessing, deadlock

I've started messing around with Go, and I'm fascinated by go routines. I now wrote a simple test to see if I can change the value of a variable while I continuously print it out.

I now have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func change(c chan float64) float64 {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    return 2.5
}

func main() {

    s := 1.1

    c := make(chan float64)
    go change(c)
    s = <-c

    for {
        fmt.Println(s)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately it ends in an error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        /home/kramer65/repos/go/src/messing_around/main.go:19 +0x7d
exit status 2
```

I searched around and found that this deadlock happens when the main function ends while goroutines didn't end yet. But since I have an endless loop I wouldn't know what else is wrong with my code.

What is wrong with this code, and how I can change the value of a variable while I continuously print it out?

Comment: Because are no sends to channel `c`, the program blocks forever on receive from `c`.  I am guessing you intended to `c <- 2.5` instead of `return 2.5` in the `change` function.

Comment: Before you get to the loop, you try to receive on `c`, but nothing ever sends on `c`.

Comment: Look at the stack trace carefully and you will see that main never makes it to the for loop. [The Tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) explains channels step by step. "Deadlock happens when the main function ends while goroutines didn't end yet" is incorrect. When main finishes the program terminates, no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a misunderstanding on channels and go routines.

The line:

```
go change(c)
```

seems to indicate that the function `change` is going to write to `c`. However it ends up just returning a value after a period of time.

This value (`2.5`) doesn't get received anywhere. Also, `c` doesn't get written to anywhere. I suspect you intended the `2.5` to be written to the channel `c`. The syntax for that is as follows:

```
c<-2.5
```

Therefore, if you change your `change` function to:

```
func change(c chan float64) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    c <- 2.5
}
```

You should not see the deadlock anymore. Notice I am not returning a `float64` anymore.

I made a playground to ensure this: https://play.golang.org/p/SgLiUmPpcAZ

**Update for Comment**

The `1.1` will always be overwritten by the value of the channel. If however you want to print `s`'s initial value (as stated in the comment), you will have to change the flow a bit and use a `select` statement:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func change(c chan float64) {
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    c <- 2.5
}

func main() {

    s := 1.1

    c := make(chan float64)
    go change(c)

    for {
        select {
        case s = <-c:
        default:
            // c isn't ready yet
        }
        fmt.Println(s)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Now that you have a `select` statement, you can use it with a `time.Ticker` as well:

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
for {
    select {
    case s = <-c:
    case <-ticker.C:
        fmt.Println(s)
    default:
        // c isn't ready yet
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I intended to do. Your code doesn't do what I expected it to do though. I expect it to start printing out `s` when it's still `1.1`, have `change()` change the value of `s` after 2 seconds, and see that reflected in the printed out value. So I expect it to print out `1.1` for 2 seconds, after which the value that is printed changes to `2.5`. So I expect the line `s = <-c` to work like a callback, but it doesn't. The program waits for a value to come out of the channel and then proceeds. Any idea how to make it update the value of `s` in the middle of the loop?